# How to check if a given path is a file or directory?

Tags: file, file-io, path, directory, rust

I'm building a program that should be able to take both paths to files (`*.*`), and directories (`./`, `..`). I want to be able to check if the path supplied is a file, or a directory.

Comment: Unclear to me. Please give more details on the use case.

Comment: @kebs The main use case would be that if the user provided one file, or just all files in a directory of a certain type ie: `./*.js`, it it would only work through those files, but if the user wanted all files contained within a directory, I need to be able to go through it recursively( I know there is walk_dir that does this, but it is unstable). Or if the user combined both, and provided both a link to files, and a link to a directory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of `rustc 1.67.1 (d5a82bbd2 2023-02-07)` you can use `std::path::PathBuf`:

```
let path = PathBuf::from(".");
let is_dir = path.is_dir();
let is_file = path.is_file();
println!("is_dir: {is_dir}");
println!("is_file : {is_file}");
```

This is the output when you execute the code with a REPL:

```
Welcome to evcxr. For help, type :help
>> use std::path::PathBuf;
>> let path = PathBuf::from(".");
>> let is_dir = path.is_dir();
>> let is_file = path.is_file();
>> println!("is_dir: {is_dir}");
is_dir: true
>> println!("is_file : {is_file}");
is_file : false
```

Answer (score 46):

You should use [`std::fs::metadata`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.metadata.html):

```
use std::fs::metadata;

fn main() {
    let md = metadata(".").unwrap();
    println!("is dir: {}", md.is_dir());
    println!("is file: {}", md.is_file());
}
```

Output:

```
is dir: true
is file: false
```

Comment: For reference, the Rust API docs have [reasonable search results](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.metadata.html?search=dir) for "dir". The third result at the time of writing is the solution in this answer.

Comment: @Shepmaster Yeah, but to be fair, the second result is `PathExt::is_dir`, which is unstable and therefore probably not what the asker is looking for, even though it also does what they want.

Comment: that's why I said "reasonable" not "great". ^_^ Hopefully that will only get better! I mostly wanted to point out that the API reference can be a good resource as well.

Comment: I was looking in the Rust docs, but i was thinking it would be part of `std::fs::File`, or `std::path::Path`.

Comment: For Rust 1.5+, PathBuf has `is_file`